# Deserialize xml base on attribute name as properties of my class in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have xml file like i describe below

```
<Root name="myRoot">
    <Field name = "myField">"blabla</Field>
    <List name="data">
        <Row name="data">
            <Field name="Field1">sample</Field>
            <Field name="Field2">sample</Field>
        </Row>     
    </List>
</Root>
```

I want to mapping this xml file to this class:

```
public class Row
{
    public string Field1
    {
        get;set;
    }

    public string Field2
    {
        get;set;
    }
}
```

my problem is how to mapping atrribute name to properties of "Row" class ?
by the way i able to mapping to properties of "Row" class based on tag (Field).
my point is how to mapping with extra condition which is with value of attribute name on field tag?

sorry for my english.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: google for `XmlAttribute`

Comment: @I4V that won't help here

Comment: Note: what you are laying out in xml there looks a lot like the "inner platform effect"... xml can *already* express roots, fields and lists - including names. You've neatly rebuilt the features of xml *inside xml*. That usually means you are using it incorrectly.

Comment: thank you so much Marc. Your comment and answer is very helpfull. Actually i was already mapping my XML class to instance(row) class using reflection and copy all values into properties in "Row" class. Why i asking here, because i need advice how to do it with diffrent approach so i can compare performances of each approaches. So again, your comment and answer is very helpfull, cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No inbuilt xml serializer (in particular, neither `XmlSerializer` nor `DataContractSerializer`) allows you to use the *value* of an attribute to map to a member. The *name* of an attribute - sure (for example `<cust id="12345" name="Fred"/>`) - but not your `<Field name="Field2">...</Field>`.

Consequently, you will have to do this manually using something like `XmlDocument`, `XDocument` or `XmlReader`. Alternatively, perhaps run it through xslt to turn it into something that `XmlSerializer` *can* handle, i.e. you could construct (via xslt):

```
<myRoot>
    <myField>"blabla</myField>
    <data>
        <data>
            <Field1>sample</Field1>
            <Field2>sample</Field2>
        </data>
    </data>
</myRoot>
```

(which would involve use of `<xsl:element name="@name">` in particular)