# Mapping XML file to a C# class

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xmlserializer

I know that deserializing xml to C# classes is a common thing and I've done it before. But ive received an XML file with a format im having a hard time deserializing properly. When i generate a C# class from the XML. I get a format I dont want. Basically all the properties get the column type..

The basic XML format is like below. The thing is  that I have 250 properties and I really don't want to manually map every single one.

```
<item table="Order">
    <column columnName="Id"><![CDATA[2]]></column>
    <column columnName="Price"><![CDATA[200]]></column>
    <column columnName="Date"><![CDATA[25-01-2036 13:29:24:310]]>
```

I've actually manually written a class that has the correct properties. `Id`, `price`, `date` and so on...

I've tried with adding `ElementName` and `AttributeName` with no luck. Is it possible for me to map this directly to a C# class using `XmlSerializer`?

It perfectly maps the autogenerated class but it ends up with a list of colums and columnName..

Do anyone know if I can possible fix this with some xml notations on my c# class to get it too map properly?

-------------- Solution --------------

Thanks to @Dan Field for getting me on the right track!

as he points out himself there was a problem with nullable attributes in his solution. So i hunted another one down and this is what i came up with!

```
   public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "column")
            {
                PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(EcomOrder));
                string propName = reader.GetAttribute("columnName");

                // Retrieve the property Descriptor
                PropertyDescriptor prop = props[propName];

                if (prop != null)
                {
                    reader.Read(); // move to CDATA (or text) node

                    // use DateTime.ParseExact instead for DateTime field
                    if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?) || prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
                    {
                        prop.SetValue(this,
                             DateTime.ParseExact(reader.Value, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        prop.SetValue(this,
                             prop.Converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(reader.Value));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new XmlException("Property not found: " + propName);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us what you already tried?

Comment: Show us the class you are using for deserialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Dan Field for getting me on the right track!

as he points out himself there was a problem with nullable attributes in his solution. So i hunted another one down and this is what i came up with!

```
   public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "column")
            {
                PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(EcomOrder));
                string propName = reader.GetAttribute("columnName");

                // Retrieve the property Descriptor
                PropertyDescriptor prop = props[propName];

                if (prop != null)
                {
                    reader.Read(); // move to CDATA (or text) node

                    // use DateTime.ParseExact instead for DateTime field
                    if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?) || prop.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
                    {
                        prop.SetValue(this,
                             DateTime.ParseExact(reader.Value, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        prop.SetValue(this,
                             prop.Converter.ConvertFromInvariantString(reader.Value));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new XmlException("Property not found: " + propName);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using XSLT to transform the XML to something `XmlSerializer` can read, but if it's just this, I think this is a case where you'll want to implement `IXmlSerializable` on a custom class.  Here's something I whipped together, using reflection to parse the `columnName` into a property in the `Order` class.

If you need to serialize back to this format, it should be fairly trivial to do.

```
[XmlRoot("item")]
public class Order  : IXmlSerializable
{

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema GetSchema()
    {
        return null;
    }

    public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && reader.Name == "column")
            {
                string propName = reader.GetAttribute("columnName"); // get the property info...
                PropertyInfo prop = typeof(Order).GetProperty(propName, 
                      BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.SetProperty);
                if (prop != null && prop.CanWrite)
                {
                    reader.Read(); // move to CDATA (or text) node
                    // can use Convert.ChangeType for most types
                    // use DateTime.ParseExact instead for DateTime field
                    if (prop.PropertyType != typeof(DateTime))
                    {
                        prop.SetValue(this, 
                             Convert.ChangeType(reader.Value, prop.PropertyType, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        prop.SetValue(this, 
                             DateTime.ParseExact(reader.Value,  "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss:fff", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture));
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new XmlException("Property not found: " + propName);
                }
            }                    

        }
    }

    public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

You'll probably have to do a little more work if there are any other types in there that need special parsing considerations.  This will throw an exception if you get an empty value for an `int` node though - might work just using `int?` if that's the case.  It also doesn't include any kind of auto-class generation - I'd write a utility to do that if there were lots of properties at play or if they changed frequently.

Comment: I'll definitely try this when i get time! I'll write again when i hopefully get it working! ;) 
If i understand correctly, i can just call my deserializer like normal and it will use this readXml instead of the default one?

Comment: It'd definitely need a bit more fleshing out for real use - some types won't convert propertly just using `Convert.ChangeType`, and it won't deal with nulls if you have nullable fields as is.

Comment: And yes, it will call the `ReadXml` method to actually do the deserialization work.

Comment: Thanks alot man! i found another way that made handling nullables alot easiere :) ive updated my question with the solution!
Now i have a final question for you :D 
How do i easily make a test method too test that all properties get the correct value? <.<  without manually going through 250 properties

Comment: If you have a solution, you should post it as an answer.  If you'd like to accept it as the answer that's fine, although if this answer was helpful and got you to it you could also accept this one (or at least vote it up).  As far as validation goes, I'd write a unit test method that has an embedded XML sample that you know should fill every property with a valid value, and iterate through the `.GetProperties()` of the type to make sure each one is set.

Comment: Thanks! I already voted you up but dont have the reputation for it too count yet..

Comment: Got a last question for you! :)  Do you know how i can grap all items where the Price is == 200 .. im not having any success with either xpathselectelements or selectnodes...  a solution using either would be awesome

Comment: Post it as a separate question - it depends on how you're doing it (what class you're using to access the XML or whether it's in the object you're creating).  Or do you want to do that in the ReadXml method?  If so then just check if the propName == "Price" ...

Comment: Im grabbing an item node in this question.. and deserializing it too an object...  I have other item nodes but with different table names.. Some of these items have an Order as a parent.. and i wanna find the items with a specific parent so i can add them to the model :)  But i guess your right it deserves a seperate question to get more details

Comment: Ive posted the question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35514071/how-to-find-xmlnodes-based-on-a-child-elements-name-and-value
thanks alot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think is not possible to map directly. 
You can use XPathNavigator to do a mapping or you can follow the recomendtions of [Marc Gravell in the following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684883/deserialize-xml-base-on-attribute-name-as-properties-of-my-class-in-c-sharp) 
[Deserialize xml base on attribute name as properties of my class in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16684883/deserialize-xml-base-on-attribute-name-as-properties-of-my-class-in-c-sharp)