# How to find XmlNodes based on a child elements name and value

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, linq-to-xml, xmldocument

Im having trouble getting a XmlNodeList where there is 1 child with a specific name that

```
<tables>
  <table tableName="Orders">
    <item table="Orders">
      ...
   </item>
    <item table="Orders">
      ...
   </item>
  </table>
  <table tableName="OrderWithParent">
    <item table="OrderWithParent">
      <column columnName="OrderWithParentId"><![CDATA[156]]></column>
      <column columnName="OrderParentId"><![CDATA[1]]></column>
      ...
   </item>
    <item table="OrderWithParent">
      <column columnName="OrderWithParentId"><![CDATA[156]]></column>
      <column columnName="OrderParentId"><![CDATA[1]]></column>
      ...
   </item>
    <item table="OrderWithParent">
      <column columnName="OrderWithParentId"><![CDATA[156]]></column>
      <column columnName="OrderParentId"><![CDATA[2]]></column>
      ...
   </item>
  </table>
</tables>
```

So thats my basic xml layout...

Ive deserialized the top Orders... and now i wanna find the OrderWithParent's where their column with columnName="OrderParentId" == order.Id

the order nodes where retrieved like this:

```
var orders = root.SelectNodes("/tables/table[@tableName='Orders']/item[@table='Orders']");
```

So atm im using an XmlDocument.. im hope to using XDocument aswell.. but i havent been able to find a solution with either of them. Help is much appreciated!

Comment: Can you post a valid sample of your XML?  Doesn't have to be full, but enough to test.

Comment: Should be enough. the only thing missing is the top tag <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

i wanna select all OrderWithParent where the column with columnName="OrderParentId" has the value 1 as an example..

Comment: It's missing closing tags

Comment: alright updated. now with 3 OrderWithParent.. so if i search for the one with OrderParentId = 1.. i wanna get 2 out of the 3 ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `order.Id` means `Id` property of a predefined variable `order` which you didn't show, the following XPath should return the target `item` element :

```
var xpath = $"//item[@table='OrderWithParent' and column[@columnName='OrderWithParentId'] = {order.Id}]";
```

For older C# version where string interpolation `$` is not supported :

```
var xpath = String.Format("//item[@table='OrderWithParent' and column[@columnName='OrderWithParentId'] = {0}]", order.Id);
```

Another assumption is, that `order.Id` value is always number. Otherwise you'll need to wrap the value with quotes in the XPath i.e in the above snippet, replace `{order.Id}` with `'{order.Id}'` or `{0}` with `'{0}'`.

If you switch to using `XDocument`, you can still execute the same XPath expression through [`XPathSelectElements()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.xpathselectelements%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), [`XPathSelectElement()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.xpathselectelement%28v=vs.90%29.aspx), or [`XPathEvaluate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.xpathevaluate%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think your searching for the wrong node in your syntax.  Try this, see if it helps:

```
var orders = root.SelectNodes("/tables/table[@tableName='OrderWithParent']/item[@table='OrderWithParent']");
```

this assumes I'm not misunderstanding the question though.

Comment: The line for SelectNodes where the one i used to select the Orders... those are easy because i want all of them... but now i wanna select all the OrderWithParent's where their column with columnName="OrderParentId" has a specific value.  The line you post will get all of them and not filter on OrderParentId

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" +
                    "<tables>" +
                      "<table tableName=\"Orders\">" +
                        "<item table=\"Orders\">" +
                          "..." +
                        "</item>" +
                        "<item table=\"Orders\">" +
                          "..." +
                        "</item>" +
                      "</table>" +
                      "<table tableName=\"OrderWithParent\">" +
                        "<item table=\"OrderWithParent\">" +
                          "<column columnName=\"OrderWithParentId\"><![CDATA[156]]></column>" +
                          "<column columnName=\"OrderParentId\"><![CDATA[1]]></column>" +
                          "..." +
                        "</item>" +
                        "<item table=\"OrderWithParent\">" +
                          "<column columnName=\"OrderWithParentId\"><![CDATA[156]]></column>" +
                          "<column columnName=\"OrderParentId\"><![CDATA[1]]></column>" +
                          "..." +
                        "</item>" +
                        "<item table=\"OrderWithParent\">" +
                          "<column columnName=\"OrderWithParentId\"><![CDATA[156]]></column>" +
                          "<column columnName=\"OrderParentId\"><![CDATA[2]]></column>" +
                          "..." +
                        "</item>" +
                      "</table>" +
                    "</tables>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

            XElement[] results = doc.Descendants("table").Elements("item")
                .Where(y => ((string)y.Attribute("table") == "OrderWithParent") &&
                    (y.Elements("column").Where(z => 
                       (z.Attribute("columnName") != null) &&
                       (z.Attribute("columnName").Value == "OrderParentId") &&
                       (z.Value  == "1")
                       )).Any()
                    )
                .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```